Heat dissipation pad in power resistor
I intend to use this power resistor as a load in my circuits. The datasheet does not clearly specify the pin configuration, but it includes an EPAD pin. I assume this EPAD should be connected to GND in my circuit to facilitate heat dissipation. Am I right?



With resistors in semiconductor packages the PAD is often unconnected.
You can tell because they do not specify a pinout, and they mention
Insulation Resistance 10 GΩ.
But the best clue can be found in the text:
"Resistor electrically isolated from the backplate"

thanks, then we can conclude that the PAD is isolated from resistor, so if we connect it to GND, it is electrically fine, and it can be used as heat dissipation for the package?

@Andromeda yes of course
